# What is the difference in syntax between the following queries?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, subquery

I have an huge table of policies and I need to find all policies with invalid movements. For example, if inforce - premium_paid to terminated - premium_paid is invalid, then I would need to find all policies with this movement.

My query was initially as follows:

```
SELECT *,
       LEAD(STAT) OVER (PARTITION BY ID, ORDER BY PROCDT, PROCTIME) AS NEXT_STAT,
       LEAD(EVENT) OVER (PARTITION BY ID, ORDER BY PROCDT, PROCTIME) AS NEXT_EVENT
FROM TABLE
WHERE STAT = 'inforce',
      EVENT = 'premium_paid',
      NEXT_STAT = 'terminated',
      NEXT_EVENT = 'premium_paid'
ORDER BY STAT, EVENT, NEXT_STAT, NEXT_EVENT
```

However, when I ran it, the compiler said that my column names 'NEXT_POLSTAT' and 'NEXT_EVENT' were invalid. Then, when I tweaked it to the following, it worked:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
       SELECT *,
              LEAD(STAT) OVER (PARTITION BY ID, ORDER BY PROCDT, PROCTIME) AS NEXT_STAT,
              LEAD(EVENT) OVER (PARTITION BY ID, ORDER BY PROCDT, PROCTIME) AS NEXT_EVENT
       FROM TABLE) AS a
WHERE a.STAT = 'inforce',
      a.EVENT = 'premium_paid',
      a.NEXT_STAT = 'terminated',
      a.NEXT_EVENT = 'premium_paid'
ORDER BY a.STAT, a.EVENT, a.NEXT_STAT, a.NEXT_EVENT
```

Thus, I am just curious to know why my initial query did not work.

Comment: Because SQL Server has not yet computed the values you are trying to use in the `where` clause of your first attempt. Calculated columns have to be in a sub-query of some sort to be used in the `where` clause.

Comment: @DaleK I see... so the correct syntax for this is what I had written in my edited query?

Comment: Yes, your last attempt is exactly how to do it.

Comment: @DaleK Thank you :)

Comment: @EthanMark . . . It is not clear what the correct syntax is, because you have not explained what you are trying to do.  You might want to ask another question with a clear explanation and sample data.